# Finding Django source code based on import

Tags: python, django

I found a package extending the `models.BigIntegerField` in Django and I'm running into a bug with it, so I'm trying to look at the `BigIntegerField`'s source code. Unfortunately the package imports `from django.db import models` and then calls `models.BigIntegerField`, but if I go to https://github.com/django/django, all /django/db/models is a folder, not a file, and I can't find BigIntegerField anywhere. Is there any way to actually figure out where stuff is in the source code?

Comment: Shang Wang has already given a better answer, but if you want the actual github line it is found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1847)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search github repo, for example for a [class definition](https://github.com/django/django/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22class+BigIntegerField%22&type=Code).

When importing `models` Python looks for a file named `models.py` or for a `models/__init__.py` file if `models` is a directory. The latter file has a 
`from django.db.models.fields import *` line which import the `BigIntegerField`

Comment: Oh man, I feel dumb. I was fixating on the "Find File" button and couldn't figure out why there wasn't a general search option.

Answer (score 4):

Check django doc about [`BigIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield), there's a `[source]` link beside it, which basically points you to the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#BigIntegerField).

<sub>When in doubt, Django doc is your best friend.</sub>

Comment: Ah, thats nice. I also found it in the github. I didn't think to check the `__init__.py`